# How to vertical align my tag in my case

Tags: html, css

I am trying to do a vertical align middle in my case.

I have.

```
<section id='container'>
    <div id='title'> 
         <h1>Title here.</h1>
     </div>
</section>
```

I have my css like

```
#title{
display: inline-block;
width: 235px;
height: 94px;
position: relative;
text-align: center;
}

#left-lesson-title h1{
color:white;
line-height: 94px;
vertical-align: middle;
text-align: left;
font:normal 1.3em arial;
margin-left:15px
}
```

I can't seem to get `h1` texts vertical aligned to middle. The h1 is aligned to top in my case. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#title{
    border:1px solid black;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 235px;
    height: 94px;
    vertical-align:middle;
    text-align: center;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WC6t8/

You need to set your display to table-cell then set the vertical-align as middle.

This should be on the parent container of the h1 tag.

Comment: but I need to have the display as inline-block to accommodate my needs.

Comment: Try this to see if it will work for what you need (inline-block solution) assuming that you already know the size of the container (I added the borders as a visual):  http://jsfiddle.net/WC6t8/1/